# SLES 12: Client service neither service nor target?

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, sles

I am using SLES 12 VM where I have installed an rpm. While installing rpm I get the following Note

```
hostname:~ # rpm -ivh BESAgent-9.5.8.38-sle11.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:BESAgent-9.5.8.38-sle11          ################################# [100%]

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
systemd configuration.

If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
To see services enabled on particular target use
'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

besclient                 0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
```

when I try to start the service I keep getting error

```
hostname:~ # service besclient start
besclient is neither service nor target!?
```

I think this is because of the note received when I install the RPM. I also noticed `systemctl list-unit-files` does not list `besclient.service`

When I try to start the service using init.d I get the following

```
hostname:~ #  /etc/init.d/besclient start
redirecting to systemctl start besclient.service
Failed to start besclient.service: Unit besclient.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Here are OS release details:

```
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 2
# This file is deprecated and will be removed in a future service pack or release.
# Please check /etc/os-release for details about this release.
NAME="SLES_SAP"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for SAP Applications 12 SP2"
ID="sles_sap"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles_sap:12:sp2"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues you are getting are related to the different ways services are managed on SUSE 11 and SUSE 12. Looking at the info you provided seems you are trying to install a package that contains a service that is targeted for SUSE 11 on a SUSE 12 based server.
SUSE 11.x uses sysv initd and SUSE 12.x uses systemd for services management. You should get a package supporting SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 or use the initd script in the current package to create your own systemd version of the service definition. Usually it's quite straight forward. [Example](https://serverfault.com/questions/690155/whats-the-easiest-way-to-make-my-old-init-script-work-in-systemd): https://serverfault.com/questions/690155/whats-the-easiest-way-to-make-my-old-init-script-work-in-systemd

Answer (score 0):

The issues is related to the action site masthead file (actionsite.afxm) that can be found in your BES Installation folders. Copy your actionsite masthead to the Linux BES Client (the masthead contains configuration, license, and security information). The masthead should be named "actionsite.afxm, so rename it to "actionsite.afxm" and place it at the following location: /etc/opt/BESClient/actionsite.afxm.
Then start the BigFix Client by running the command /etc/init.d/besclient start

```
# ls  /etc/opt/BESClient/actionsite.afxm
/etc/opt/BESClient/actionsite.afxm

# service besclient start

# systemctl status besclient.service
● besclient.service - LSB: Start BESClient daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/besclient; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since...
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 35168 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/besclient start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/besclient.service
           ├─35178 /opt/BESClient/bin/BESClient
           └─35179 /opt/BESClient/bin/BESClient -RPMHelper
```